# Error while downloading pyqt5.. Using the latest version of pip and sip version 15.0.2 (Using Mac Os Big Sur 11.5.2-apple silicon)

Tags: pip, pyqt5, python-3.8

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /Users/siddhantsrivastava/Desktop/PROGRAMMING/PythonProjects/AI_Assistant/bin/python /Users/siddhantsrivastava/Desktop/PROGRAMMING/PythonProjects/AI_Assistant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel /var/folders/lm/1n6xwbk14939ct0z6xl1qbvw0000gn/T/tmpkrnkoe2y
             cwd: /private/var/folders/lm/1n6xwbk14939ct0z6xl1qbvw0000gn/T/pip-install-ppgn_c8e/pyqt5_45bc8def44524a95a74a079d41ea15ba
        Complete output (29 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/siddhantsrivastava/Desktop/PROGRAMMING/PythonProjects/AI_Assistant/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 143, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
            hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
        AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
```

Trying to install pyqt5 using pip3 with command pip3 install pyqt5, getting me to this error ...other solutions suggest me to upgrade pip to the latest version.done that still givingme this error? what to do now?

Comment: use `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` `python -m pip install pyqt5`, what is your OS?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am using mac os Big sur 11.5.2 (apple silicon) ...and the above command which you suggested ,i have tried upgrading pip and the installing but still having error and btw i am using pip3 instead of pip and python3 instead of python! that would not create any problem .right?

Comment: I recommend you edit your post so that you indicate that you use macos, if you do, I will reopen your post.

Comment: sure @eyllanesc

Comment: try with: `python -m pip install pyqt5 --only-binary pyqt5`

Comment: Using the only binary command it is giving me this error:                          
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5